# i want to show the row which it,s checkbox was checked in datagridview and hide the others rows unchecked

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

i have a datagridview and i have a column of checkboxes  my code is

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
        row = dataGridView1.Rows[i];

        if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value) == true)
        {
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource =
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need DataSource to do it. But you may need it if you want to show them all again.

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
         if (!Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value))
         {
             dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
             row.Visible = false;
         }
    }
```

Comment: Uncommitted new row cannot be made invisible.

Comment: I edited my answer. just add this line before making row visible false => 
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;


let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
row.Visible = false;
```

Just make sure at the beginning You can do that:

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help  the second text you wrote benefited me  